# Retreive balance (amount due) via api or as a field in drupal views

Tags: civicontribute

I am wondering if it would be possible / difficult to retrieve the balance of a contribution through the api (3 or 4) and / or if it could be exposed as a field in drupal views or standard civicrm reports.

Answer (score 0):

I just found this issue. This does not answer my question fully but is related
https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/2890